# Getting a data structure equivalent to asXML() in pyparsing?

Tags: python, pyparsing

I learned that in pyparsing, you can name an element/group/node by doing this:

```py
token = pyparsing.Literal("Foobar")("element_name_here")
```

So, I made a sample program to test it out:

```py
import pyparsing as pp

Prefix = pp.Word(pp.nums)("Prefix")
Name = pp.Literal("FOOBAR")("Name")
Modifier = pp.Word(pp.alphas)("Modifier")
Modifier_Group = pp.Group(pp.OneOrMore(Modifier))("Modifier_Group")
Sentence = pp.Group(pp.Optional(Prefix) + Name + Modifier_Group)("Sentence")

out = Sentence.parseString("123 FOOBAR testA testB")
```

Then, I tried getting the output with these named tokens.

I tried this:

```py
>>> print out
[['123', 'FOOBAR', ['testA', 'testB']]]
```

...but that doesn't get me the token names.

I then tried doing the following:

```py
>>> print out.items()
[('Sentence', (['123', 'FOOBAR', (['testA', 'testB'], {'Modifier': [('testA', 0), 
('testB', 1)]})], {'Modifier_Group': [((['testA', 'testB'], {'Modifier': [('testA', 0),
('testB', 1)]}), 2)], 'Prefix': [('123', 0)], 'Name': [('FOOBAR', 1)]}))]

>>> print dict(out)

{'Sentence': (['123', 'FOOBAR', (['testA', 'testB'], {'Modifier': [('testA', 0), 
('testB', 1)]})], {'Modifier_Group': [((['testA', 'testB'], {'Modifier': [('testA', 0),
('testB', 1)]}), 2)], 'Prefix': [('123', 0)], 'Name': [('FOOBAR', 1)]})}

>>> import collections
>>> print collections.OrderedDict(out)
OrderedDict([('Sentence', (['123', 'FOOBAR', (['testA', 'testB'], {'Modifier': [
('testA', 0), ('testB', 1)]})], {'Modifier_Group': [((['testA', 'testB'], 
{'Modifier': [('testA', 0), ('testB', 1)]}), 2)], 'Prefix': [('123', 0)], 
'Name': [('FOOBAR', 1)]}))])
```

...but they contained a peculiar mixture of dicts, lists, and tuples, and I couldn't figure out how to parse them.  Then, I tried doing this:

```xml
>>> print out.asXML()
<Sentence>
  <Sentence>
    <Prefix>123</Prefix>
    <Name>FOOBAR</Name>
    <Modifier_Group>
      <Modifier>testA</Modifier>
      <Modifier>testB</Modifier>
    </Modifier_Group>
  </Sentence>
</Sentence>
```

...and that got me EXACTLY what I wanted, except that it's in XML, instead of a python data structure that I can easily manipulate.  Is there some way to get such a data structure (without having to parse the XML)?

I did find a solution that returns a [nested dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9995627/cant-get-pyparsing-dict-to-return-nested-dictionary), but dicts in python are unordered, (and I want the tokens in order), so it isn't a solution for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pyparsing returns a ParseResults object that already gives you that structure. You can visualize your sentence structure by printing `out.dump()`:

```
>>> print out.dump()
[['123', 'FOOBAR', ['testA', 'testB']]]
- Sentence: ['123', 'FOOBAR', ['testA', 'testB']]
  - Modifier_Group: ['testA', 'testB']
    - Modifier: testB
  - Name: FOOBAR
  - Prefix: 123
```

You can access these elements as if they were keys in a dict:

```
>>> print out.Sentence.keys()
['Modifier_Group', 'Prefix', 'Name']
>>> print out.Sentence['Prefix']
123
```

or as attributes on an object:

```
>>> print out.Sentence.Name
FOOBAR
>>> print out.Sentence.Prefix
123
```