# MaybeEncodingError with pyparsing.asDict when using multiprocessing.pool map()

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, pyparsing

I'm trying to use `multiprocessing.pool` to speed up some parsing of a file parsed using `pyparsing`, however I get a `multiprocessing.pool.MaybeEncodingError` exception whenever I try this.

I've narrowed it down to something to do with returning a dictionary (`ParseResults.asDict()`), using `asList()` the error doesn't occur; but the input I'm actually parsing is pretty complex so ideally I'd like to use `asDict`.

The actual data being parsed is an Erlang list of tagged tuples, which I want to map to a python list. The grammar for this is pretty complex, so I've instead got a simplified test case (**updated to include a nested dict**):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
from pyparsing import *
import multiprocessing

dictionary = Forward()
key = Word(alphas)
sep   = Suppress(":")
value = ( key | dictionary )
key_val = Group( key + sep + value )
dictionary <<= Dict( Suppress('[') + delimitedList( key_val ) + Suppress(']') )

def parse_dict(s):
    p = dictionary.parseString(s).asDict()
    return p

def parse_list(s):
    return dictionary.parseString(s).asList()

# This works (list)
data = ['[ foo : [ bar : baz ] ]']
pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
pool.map(parse_list, data)

# This fails (dict)
pool.map(parse_dict, data)
```

Fails with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lib/python/nutshell/multi_parse.py", line 19, in <module>
    pool.map(parse, data)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 250, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 554, in get
    raise self._value
multiprocessing.pool.MaybeEncodingError: Error sending result: '[{'foo': ([(['bar', 'baz'], {})], {'bar': [('baz', 0)]})}]'. Reason: 'TypeError("'str' object is not callable",)'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: The question has significantly changed since the update. The original point of not being pickable still stands and is left below.

You say in your grammar you use a `delimitedList`, so let's add that to our test case:

```
data = ['[ foo : [ bar : baz ], cat:dog ]']
```

There is no reason why your "`dictionary`" grammar object is a python dict, it is a list. If you didn't mean that you'll have to change `delimitedList` to something else. I've updated grammar to allow for a proper pickling using a `parseAction`:

```
dictionary = Forward()
key   = Word(alphas)
LP, RP, sep = map(Suppress, "[]:")
value = key | dictionary
key_val = key("key") + sep + value("val")
dictionary <<= LP + delimitedList( key_val ) + RP

def parse_key_val(x): return {x.key:x.val}
key_val.setParseAction(parse_key_val)

def parse_dict(s):
    # Yes, it's a list, not a dict!
    return dictionary.parseString(s).asList()

def parse_list(s):
    return dictionary.parseString(s).asList()
```

This gives a working answer in parallel:

```
[[{'foo': {'bar': 'baz'}}, {'cat': 'dog'}]]
```

**Original answer:**
I think that multiprocessing fails since it can't pickle the object. You *think* you have a dict, but if you look at:

```
def parse_dict(s):
    val = lang.parseString(s).asDict()
    print type(val["foo"])
    return val
```

You'll find out that the inner type is a `<class 'pyparsing.ParseResults'>`. I'm not sure how to apply `pp.Dict` recursively, but a really simple fix would be to change your grammar:

```
value = ( Word(alphas) )
sep   = Suppress(":")
key_val = Group( value + sep + value )
lang = Dict( Suppress('[') + delimitedList( key_val ) + Suppress(']') )
```

Which now allows `pp.Dict` to operate properly. For what it's worth, I've found that many of my multiprocessing woes come from an object that can't be properly serialized, so it's usually the first place I look.

A useful and related question:

[Can't get pyparsing Dict() to return nested dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9995627/cant-get-pyparsing-dict-to-return-nested-dictionary)

Comment: Thanks - in the example I gave Suppress()ing the colon does fix the problem, however in that case I over-simplified my testcase as I get the problem in the real grammar. Let me try and get a more representative test case...

Comment: I've update the example - Suppressing the separator isn't enough to fix it. I'll look into the source for asDict().

Comment: @DaveRigby I've updated my answer. I think you have some problems with your grammar def. or your example isn't complete enough. Either way, any new updates might be better served as a new question.

Comment: Thanks again, I'm getting closer. The actual grammar I'm parsing is erlang data structures which essentially do map to a dictionary (it's an arbitrarily ordered list of key-value pairs; where the value can be nested). So in other words I **do** need to return a dict, as the test case has.

Comment: @DaveRigby You might be better off (in a new question, and link here), posting your grammar and some sample code + expected output. Paul, the author of pyparsing is on here quite a bit and might help and we as a community can look over the complete picture.

Comment: marking as answered, as in the example I gave your solution does work :) However I'm still not there with the Erlang, will raise another Q shortly...